# CRM Linq and Attribute Value

Tags: c#, linq

I have a quick question regarding LINQ and attributes in CRM. I am having some issue with this little piece of code that I am attempting to write.

```
//Create query to get the related regular rates
var rateres = from r in ServiceContext.CreateQuery("pafo_rate")
              where r["pafo_assignmentid"].Equals(entity.Id)
              select r;



//Exception Rate - excluding pto
//   var eateres = from er in ServiceContext.CreateQuery("pafo_exceptionrate")
//                 where er["pafo_assignmentid"].Equals(entity.Id) && er["pafo_assignmentid"] != ""                                  
//                 select er;

foreach (var r in rateres)
{
      Entity e = (Entity)r;
      // e["pafo_billrate"] = newbillupdate + payupdate;
      // test = (decimal)e.Attributes["pafo_payrate"]; \\ <-- How do you fix?  
      // test = 6;
      e["pafo_payrate"] = (newpayupdate + test);
      // ServiceContext.Attach(e);
      ServiceContext.UpdateObject(e);
      ServiceContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

When the plugin fires I get a message along the lines of:

> Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.SaveChangesException: An error occured while
>   processing this request.

I think it has to do with the way I am assigning to variable. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am quite not sure if it has anything to do with your linq query. But did you try wrapping `ServiceContext.SaveChanges();` in a `try...catch` statement and check inner exception etc. details?

Comment: I used a different approach using Context course.